# Extract data but include specific record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have been given an interesting challenge by my boss.  We have a dataset to extract certain advertisers on a page but if you are an advertiser who is logged in, he wants to make sure that persons ad shows first.  Here is the script as it stand right now:

```
SELECT TOP 15
a.MemberID,             -- 0
a.UserName,             -- 1
a.MemberDisplayName,    -- 2
a.NYKABizName           -- 3
FROM Member a
INNER JOIN AdDisplay b ON b.MemberID = a.MemberID
WHERE a.Claimed = 'Y'
AND a.NYKACatID IS NOT NULL
AND b.LocalPageID = @LocalPageID
AND a.SBIcon = 'N'
AND a.Viewable = 'Y'
AND a.ProfileTypeID <> 1
AND a.PackageType <> 'G'
AND a.PackageType <> 'P'
AND a.PackageType <> 'C'
ORDER BY PackageType ASC
```

I want to add some like Include MemberID = 102.  How can I change this script to accomplish the bosses wishes.

Many thanks in advance,

neojakey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the query returns the advertiser in question (without the top 15), you can do this my modifying the order by clause:

```
order by (case when MemberId = 102 then 0 else 1 end),
         PackageType ASC
```

This orders the list putting the desired member first, followed by everything else.  You can still keep the top 15 in the query.

Comment: I think this might be a more elegant way of doing the same thing I answered (and you answered first, although I didn't see it until after I wrote mine).  +1 for you.

Comment: Worked perfectly.. so simple, just the way I like my code.  Many thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a lot here, but the idea is to add your logged-in-users table to the query and make sure anybody with a record in that table shows up.

```
SELECT TOP 15
a.MemberID,             -- 0
a.UserName,             -- 1
a.MemberDisplayName,    -- 2
a.NYKABizName           -- 3
FROM Member a
INNER JOIN AdDisplay b ON b.MemberID = a.MemberID
LEFT OUTER JOIN LoggedInUsers l ON a.MemberID = l.MemberID
WHERE (a.Claimed = 'Y'
AND a.NYKACatID IS NOT NULL
AND b.LocalPageID = @LocalPageID
AND a.SBIcon = 'N'
AND a.Viewable = 'Y'
AND a.ProfileTypeID <> 1
AND a.PackageType <> 'G'
AND a.PackageType <> 'P'
AND a.PackageType <> 'C')
OR l.MemberID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY IF(l.MemberID IS NOT NULL,0,1), PackageType ASC
```

Of course if you just always want to statically include MemberID = 102, then @GordonLinoff's answer is the correct one. Maybe I'm reading into your question too much.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a second query similar to the first one but which returns only the results for your logged-in members, and have both queries include an additional value to identify which subquery they came from, then union them and select from them in an outer query which orders them.

I know that's a run-on sentence, so let me see if I can elaborate in code...

```
SELECT TOP 15 * FROM (
    SELECT
      0 as loginStatus,
      a.MemberID,             -- 0 
      a.UserName,             -- 1 
      a.MemberDisplayName,    -- 2 
      a.NYKABizName           -- 3 
    FROM Member a 
    INNER JOIN AdDisplay b 
    ON b.MemberID = a.MemberID 
    WHERE a.Claimed = 'Y' 
    AND a.NYKACatID IS NOT NULL 
    AND b.LocalPageID = @LocalPageID 
    AND a.SBIcon = 'N' 
    AND a.Viewable = 'Y' 
    AND a.ProfileTypeID <> 1 
    AND a.PackageType <> 'G' 
    AND a.PackageType <> 'P' 
    AND a.PackageType <> 'C' 
    AND a.MemberID IN (@memberIdList)

    UNION

    SELECT
      1 as loginStatus,
      a.MemberID,             -- 0 
      a.UserName,             -- 1 
      a.MemberDisplayName,    -- 2 
      a.NYKABizName           -- 3 
    FROM Member a 
    INNER JOIN AdDisplay b 
    ON b.MemberID = a.MemberID 
    WHERE a.Claimed = 'Y' 
    AND a.NYKACatID IS NOT NULL 
    AND b.LocalPageID = @LocalPageID 
    AND a.SBIcon = 'N' 
    AND a.Viewable = 'Y' 
    AND a.ProfileTypeID <> 1 
    AND a.PackageType <> 'G' 
    AND a.PackageType <> 'P' 
    AND a.PackageType <> 'C'
)
ORDER BY loginStatus
```

Comment: By the way, I'm assuming that your original query doesn't always include logged in users, and you'd want to specify those in the second unioned query.